# Не могу научить компилятор выводить и множества, и векторы

Tags: c++

У меня есть две функции, для вывода вектора и множества:

```
template <typename Element>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const set<Element>& container) {
    bool isnt_first = false;
    for (const Element& element : container) {
        if (isnt_first) {
            out << ", "s << element;
        }
        else {
            out << element;
            isnt_first = true;
        }
    }
    return out;
}

template <typename Element>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const vector<Element>& container) {
    bool isnt_first = false;
    for (const Element& element : container) {
        if (isnt_first) {
            out << ", "s << element;
        }
        else {
            out << element;
            isnt_first = true;
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Функция main:

```
int main() {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    const set<string> cats = { "Мурка"s, "Белка"s, "Георгий"s, "Рюрик"s };
    cout << cats << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Мне нужно вынести функционал вывода в отдельную функцию Print, что я и сделал:

```
template <typename Container, typename Element>
std::ostream& Print(std::ostream& out, const Container container) {
    bool isnt_first = false;
    for (const Element& element : container) {
        if (isnt_first) {
            out << ", "s << element;
        }
        else {
            out << element;
            isnt_first = true;
        }
    }
    return out;
};

template <typename Element>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const set<Element>& container) {
    out << Print(out, &container);
    return out;
}

template <typename Element>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const vector<Element>& container) {
    out << Print(out, &container);
    return out;
}
```

Но компилятор выдает ошибки при компиляции:

```
error C2672: "Print": не найдена соответствующая перегруженная функция
std::ostream &Print(std::ostream &,const Container): не удается составить аргумент шаблон для "Element"
```

Как заставить программу работать и с множествами, и с векторами?

Comment: `&` потеряли в объявлении. И наоборот, из вызовов его надо убрать.

Comment: Ситуацию это не изменило

Comment: Научить компилятору выводить _  не  правильное выражение...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызов `Print` не упоминает явно тип `Element`. Компилятор не понимает как его вывести из переданных аргументов. Ему можно подсказать, указав типы явно:

```
template <typename Container, typename Element>
std::ostream& Print(ostream& out, const Container& container) {
    bool isnt_first = false;
    for (const Element& element : container) {
        if (isnt_first) {
            out << ", " << element;
        }
        else {
            out << element;
            isnt_first = true;
        }
    }
    return out;
}

template <typename Element>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const set<Element>& container) {
    return Print<const set<Element>&, Element>(out, container);
}

template <typename Element>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const vector<Element>& container) {
    return Print<const vector<Element>&, Element>(out, container);
}
```

Я добавил пропущенный `&` в декларации `Print`. И наоборот, убрал его из вызовов. Значение возвращаемое из `Print` отправлять на печать не надо. Уже всё напечатано.

Можно схитрить и убрать тип `Element` из декларации `Print`:

```
template <typename Container>
std::ostream& Print(ostream& out, const Container& container) {
    bool isnt_first = false;
    // for (const typename Container::value_type& element : container) {
    for (const auto& element : container) {
        if (isnt_first) {
            out << ", " << element;
        }
        else {
            out << element;
            isnt_first = true;
        }
    }
    return out;
}

template <typename Element>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const set<Element>& container) {
    return Print(out, container);
}

template <typename Element>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const vector<Element>& container) {
    return Print(out, container);
}
```

Comment: А что делать, если в каждой отдельной перегрузке нужно что-то добавлять массиву или множеству? Например, если я хочу, чтобы множество выводилось как `[ 1, 2, 3]`, а векторы `{2, 5, 7}`? Как отредактировать перегрузки, не меняя Print?

Comment: передайте в функцию  символ, а вообще  можете пользоваться стандартными алгоритмами.

Comment: В этом случае `Print` менять не надо. Разные скобки печатаются перед и после содержимого в разных перегрузках.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, а как сделать так, чтобы выводились векторы векторов? По идее этих функций достаточно, но компилятор почему то выдает ошибку

Comment: Попробовал с последним кодом `vector<vector<int>>`. Работает.

Comment: Странно, у меня не работает...

Comment: Это повод задать вопрос. Не так ли?

Comment: Так и есть, пожалуй, задам

Answer (score 2):

Я бы предложил вот такой вариант, в котором не нужно ограничиваться только конкретными типами контейнеров, а уж тип элемента — это дело контейнера.

```
template <typename Container,
          typename = enable_if_t<!is_same_v<Container,string>>>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Container& container)
{
    bool isnt_first = false;
    for (const auto& element : container)
    {
        if (isnt_first) {
            out << ", "s << element;
        }
        else {
            out << element;
            isnt_first = true;
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

См. https://ideone.com/rVOs7J

Главное — объяснить оператору, что `string` — это таки не контейнер, несмотря на то, что это все же контейнер :)

Comment: Почему только строки? Должно работать для всего что печатается.

Comment: Потому что строка тоже контейнер, и он пытается вызывать самого себя рекурсивно при выводе `", "s`, например. См. https://ideone.com/ReN0iB

Comment: Это потому что вы слишком всё обобщили. В исходном коде не было такого уровня общности. Не было и проблем.

Comment: Так если не обобщать - то зачем вообще шаблоны? :) Пара перегруженных функций и хватит...

Comment: с auto  правильней, компилятор сам знает тип элементов. Что касается проверки типа, то стеки и очереди тоже не совсем контейнеры_ они адаптеры.  Тут код вывода просто изменить стоит. Можно проще...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Наверняка можно и проще, и более обобщенно. Но я, если можно так выразиться, просто наметил направление :) Да и вообще, можно через готовые библиотечные алгоритмы это делать...