# Ошибка при выводе вектора векторов при шаблонных функциях

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

У меня есть шаблонные функции, выводящие векторы и множества:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

template <typename Container>
std::ostream& Print(ostream& out, const Container& container) {
    bool isnt_first = false;
    for (const auto& element : container) {
        if (isnt_first) {
            out << ", " << element;
        }
        else {
            isnt_first = true;
            out << element;
        }
    }
    return out;
}

template <typename Element>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const set<Element>& container) {
    out << "{";
    Print(out, container);
    out << "}";
    return out;
}

template <typename Element>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const vector<Element>& container) {
    out << "[";
    Print(out, container);
    out << "]";
    return out;
}

int main() {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    const set<string> cats = { "Мурка"s, "Белка"s, "Георгий"s, "Рюрик"s };
    cout << cats << endl;

    const vector<int> ages = { 10, 5, 2, 12 };
    cout << ages << endl;

    const vector<vector<string>> a = {
        { "Мурка"s, "Белка"s, "Георгий"s, "Рюрик"s },
        { "Мурка"s, "Белка"s, "Георгий"s, "Рюрик"s },
        { "Мурка"s, "Белка"s, "Георгий"s, "Рюрик"s }
    };
    cout << a << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Но если я пытаюсь вывести вектор векторов, то компилятор выдает ошибку:

```
бинарный "<<": не найден оператор, принимающий правый операнд типа "const std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)
```

Как это исправить? Я слышал, что функции должны рекурсивно печатать векторы векторов, но у меня так и не вышло это сделать

Comment: А ведь я вам [предлагал вариант](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1482500/195342), который [справляется с вашими проблемами](https://ideone.com/6ujn8o)...

Comment: Мне нужно оставить две перегрузки, в которых я дополнительно вывожу скобки. Также, мне нельзя менять функцию Print, так что, к сожалению, ваш вариант не подходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, раз надо играть в рамках вашего ответа — без проблем, исправить ваш очень легко — просто поясните компилятору, что такие операторы есть. Проще (вернее, короче), впрочем, пояснить операторам наличие функции `Print`:

```
template <typename Container>
std::ostream& Print(ostream& out, const Container& container);


template <typename Element>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const set<Element>& container) {
    out << "{";
    Print(out, container);
    out << "}";
    return out;
}

template <typename Element>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const vector<Element>& container) {
    out << "[";
    Print(out, container);
    out << "]";
    return out;
}

template <typename Container>
std::ostream& Print(ostream& out, const Container& container) {
    bool isnt_first = false;
    for (const auto& element : container) {
        if (isnt_first) {
            out << ", ";
        }
        else {
            isnt_first = true;
        }
        out << element;
    }
    return out;
}
```

См. https://ideone.com/CdH2FE

У вас же `Print` ничего не знает о том, что оператор для вектора есть, потому что он объявлен уже после функции `Print`.

P.S. Можно, кстати, и мой вариант дописать под ваши требования (писал в спешке, Новый год на носу :), так что явно можно сделать и куда качественнее, кто исправит — не возражаю ни капли).

```
template<template <typename> class Container, typename T>
const char * pars(const Container<T>&)
{
    return "  ";
}

template<typename T>
const char * pars(const set<T>&)
{
    return "{}";
}
template<typename T>
const char * pars(const vector<T>&)
{
    return "[]";
}

template <typename Container, typename = enable_if_t<!is_same_v<Container,string>>>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Container& container)
{
    const char * p = pars(container);
    out << string(1,p[0]);
    bool isnt_first = false;
    for (const auto& element : container)
    {
        if (isnt_first) {
            out << ", "s;
        }
        else {
            isnt_first = true;
        }
        out << element;
    }
    out << string(1,p[1]);
    return out;
}
```

`main` остается все та же.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, и с наступающим!)

Comment: Равным образом! :)